# Add parallax scrolling to UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a `UIPageViewController` (and was even thinking about starting to use [Pageboy](https://github.com/uias/Pageboy)) and recently saw an app using parallax scrolling as shown [here (AnimatedCollectionView)](https://github.com/KelvinJin/AnimatedCollectionViewLayout#animatedcollectionviewlayout). Since I really liked the way parallax scrolling felt but cannot use a `UICollectionViewController` (and simply use the last mentioned pod) for my purposes due to a variety of reasons, I was wondering whether there was a way to add interactive scrolling animations or rather parallax scrolling to a `UIPageViewController` as well. At the end of the day the `UIPageViewController` is still inherited from `UIScrollView` (just like: `UITableViewController` and UICollectionViewController), right? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Nevertheless, the question remains: How can I add parallax scrolling to a `UIPageViewController`? Is it even possible? Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything that could help me.

I am not sure if it might be of any interest but the `UIPageViewController` I am using is horizontal.